# Construct knn graph from image, using python and igraph

Tags: python, image-processing, graph, igraph, knn

I have implemented the method of graph construction from image. This method is based on KNN.

Basically, each pixel represents a vertex, and it is necessary to connect each pixel with the k nearest neighbors.

The script is simple, but is very slow. I tried to optimize the calculation of the Euclidean distance and the step to add edges.

Someone has any suggestions to optimize my code?

The slowest step is the calculation of the Euclidean distance. This distance is `n^2`, due to compute the distance of all vertices for all. E.g., a image size 600x375 have 225000 vértices.

execute:

```
python file.py -f image.jpg -k 10
```

[image]

Code:

```
import Image
import math
from optparse import OptionParser
import igraph

def euclidian_distance(x1,y1,r1,g1,b1,x2,y2,r2,g2,b2):
    return math.sqrt(
        (x1 - x2) ** 2 +
        (y1 - y2) ** 2 +
        (r1 - r2) ** 2 +
        (g1 - g2) ** 2 +
        (b1 - b2) ** 2
    )

def _plot_xy(g):
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["vertex_shape"] = "circle"
    visual_style["label_color"] = "white"
    visual_style["edge_color"] = "black"
    visual_style["edge_width"] = 0.2
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 0.5

    layout = []
    for vertex in g.vs():
        layout.append((vertex["x"],vertex["y"]))

    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["bbox"] = (200, 200)
    visual_style["margin"] = 10
    igraph.plot(g, **visual_style)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = OptionParser()

    usage = "usage: python %prog [options] args ..."
    description = """Description"""
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename", help="read FILE", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-k", "--knn", dest="k", help="knn")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    filename = options.filename
    k = int(options.k)

    if filename is None:
        parser.error("required -f [filename] arg.")

    g = igraph.Graph()
    im = Image.open(filename)
    pix = im.load()
    for j in range(0,im.size[1]):
        for i in range(0,im.size[0]):
            g.add_vertex()
            vertex = g.vs[g.vcount()-1]
            vertex["name"] = vertex.index
            vertex["x"] = i
            vertex["y"] = j
            vertex["r"] = pix[i,j][0]
            vertex["g"] = pix[i,j][1]
            vertex["b"] = pix[i,j][2]

    // --> This step is very slow
    for v in g.vs():
        set_distance = dict()
        for n in g.vs():
            distance = euclidian_distance(v["x"],v["y"],v["r"],v["g"],v["b"],n["x"],n["y"],n["r"],n["g"],n["b"])
            set_distance[n.index] = distance
        sorted_set_distance = sorted(set_distance.items(), key=lambda set_distance: set_distance[1])
        v["distance"] = sorted_set_distance[:k]

    edges = []
    weight = []
    for v in g.vs():
        for n in v["distance"]:
            edges += [(v.index, n[0])]
            weight.append(n[1])

    g.add_edges(edges)
    g.es["weight"] = weight

    _plot_xy(g)

    g.write(filename.split('.')[0]+".edgelist", format='ncol')
```

Comment: Profile it, to see what is slow.

Comment: Here is a tip: do not take the square root, use the squared distance. Taking the square root is a very slow operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating the Euclidean distances for all pairs of nodes, build a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) from the nodes and then simply fetch the nearest neighbors using the kd-tree; this will cut down the number of distance calculations big time. SciPy contains an [efficient implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) of kd-trees so there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This implementation uses Euclidean distance? What it means nearest neighbor in a kd-tree?

Comment: I think this resolves the distance of eucliadiana http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tamas answer, I modified the original code. Is faster than the original code:

```
import math
from optparse import OptionParser
import igraph
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = OptionParser()

    usage = "usage: python %prog [options] args ..."
    description = """Description"""
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename", help="read FILE", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_option("-k", "--knn", dest="k", help="knn")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    filename = options.filename
    k = int(options.k)

    if filename is None:
        parser.error("required -f [filename] arg.")

    graph = igraph.Graph()
    im = Image.open(filename)
    pix = im.load()
    x, y, r, g, b = [], [], [], [], []
    for j in range(0,im.size[1]):
        for i in range(0,im.size[0]):
            graph.add_vertex()
            vertex = graph.vs[graph.vcount()-1]
            vertex["name"] = vertex.index
            vertex["x"] = i
            vertex["y"] = j
            vertex["r"] = pix[i,j][0]
            vertex["g"] = pix[i,j][1]
            vertex["b"] = pix[i,j][2]
            x.append(i)
            y.append(j)
            r.append(pix[i,j][0])
            g.append(pix[i,j][1])
            b.append(pix[i,j][2])

    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    r = np.array(r)
    g = np.array(g)
    b = np.array(b)
    tree = spatial.KDTree(zip(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), r.ravel(), g.ravel(), b.ravel()))

    edges = []
    weight = []
    for v in graph.vs():
        pts = np.array([[v["x"], v["y"], v["r"], v["g"], v["b"]]])
        list_nn = tree.query(pts, k=k);
        for idx, nn in enumerate(list_nn[1][0]):
            edges += [(v.index, nn)]
            weight.append(1/(1+list_nn[0][0][idx]))

    graph.add_edges(edges)
    graph.es["weight"] = weight

    graph.write(filename.split('.')[0]+".edgelist", format='ncol')
```